# Makefile ignores dependency every other time

Tags: makefile, build, gnu-make

I want my Makefile to do the following:

- Always run some commands when a certain file is required by the main target
- Rebuild everything that depends on that file if it changed (as result of running these commands)

In my case, this file is a C-header file that is supposed to contain version-information; I want the makefile to always update this version-header and to rebuild all files that include it.

What happens:
When I run make, the version-header update is performed every time (like I want).
But the files that depend on this header are only rebuilt every OTHER time.

Here is my stripped down Makefile:

```
SOURCES:= main.c

app.exe: $(SOURCES:%.c=%.o)
    gcc -o $@ $^

# always recompile when dependency information is missing
$(SOURCES:%.c=%.o): %.o: %.c %.d
    gcc -c $< -MMD

$(SOURCES:%.c=%.d):

version.h: update-version

update-version:
    touch version.h

# include C/C++ header-dependencies
-include $(SOURCES:%.c=%.d)

.PHONY: update-version

# disables builtin suffix-rules
.SUFFIXES:
```

Can anyone help me understand why this does not recompile every time, but only every second time?

`make` is GNU Make 4.2.1, and `remake` behaves exactly the same.

Comment: Improvement suggestion... instead of writing the pattern substitution out in each place (`$(SOURCES:%.c=%...)`), I find it much more readable to find e.g. `OBJECTS:=$(SOURCES:%.c=%.o)` and `DEPENDS:=$(SOURCES:%.c=%.d)` at the top, and the rules using those (e.g. `-include $(DEPENDS)`). -- Also, with the `-MP` option, GCC will generate the "dummy" rule for each dependency file *inside* the dependency file (removing the need for `$(SOURCES:%.c=%.d):`).

Comment: AFAICT, the `-MP` option only adds empty rules for all the *header* files, not the `*.d` files themselves. (still a good to use this flag to prevent errors after deleting header files). The empty `*.d` rules are just needed because I want to force recompilation when the object files are there but the `*.d` files are missing/deleted.

Comment: You're right, of course; good point. Depending on your needs, you might want to make the `.o`'s depend on the Makefile as well, so you get a recompile e.g. when you change the list of warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [excerpt from `make`'s manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reading-Makefiles.html#Reading-Makefiles) clarifies why your `makefile` does not work the way you intended it to:

> GNU make does its work in two distinct phases. During the first phase
>   it reads all the makefiles, included makefiles, etc. and internalizes
>   all the variables and their values, implicit and explicit rules, and
>   constructs a dependency graph of all the targets and their
>   prerequisites. During the second phase, make uses these internal
>   structures to determine what targets will need to be rebuilt and to
>   invoke the rules necessary to do so.

Since you execute your command (`touch`, in your example) inside a rule, `make` will execute it during the second phase. But by that time, the dependency graph and out-of-date targets have already been determined; that has happened in the first phase.

With this in mind, you can see why it works every other time. Your desired command *does* get executed every time, but `main.o` will only be considered out of date if the file `version.h` was already newer than `main.o` during the first phase, that is before any of the rules have been executed. So basically `main.o` will be considered out of date only if it is older than `version.h` at the moment that you invoke the `make` command. That is the case if `main.o` was not recompiled the last time you invoked `make`.

A trick you could use to execute your command in time, every time, would be to add a dummy variable somewhere at the beginning and have it execute your desired command during its evaluation. Taking `touch` again as an example command, you would be doing something like this on the first line:

```
DUMMY := $(shell touch version.h)
```

Since this is an immediate assignment, the command will be executed during the first phase. If that command updates `version.h`, then all targets that depend on `version.h` will be considered out of date and rebuilt. This includes `main.o`.

With this approach, you do not need any of the `.PHONY: update-version` mechanism and its associated rules and recipes anymore.

---

Update

Rereading, I realize that you wrote: "Always run some commands *when a certain file is required by the main target*". What do you mean by that? Further down, you wrote "When I run make, the version-header update is performed every time (like I want)" -- which is what the `makefile` resulting from this answer does. Can you clarify? And what do you mean by "main target"?

Comment: Not every target in my Makefile even requires the "version.h" file. But I don't mind updating it on *every* make invocation.  Your solutions is gonna work well for my case, many thanks!